# Stop 1 Wav File When New One Is Found

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a `powerpoint` where I have 4 `.wav` files.  They are each set to play a designated number of slides, but if I add/delete any slides, this will get skewed.  Is there a way in `powerpoint` to set the `.wav` file to play until a slide is reached that holds a different `.wav` file?

I also tried to do the "loop until next sound" option, but that keeps wav1 playing while wav2 starts and has both of them playing together.

Currently my settings are these, if there is a diff way of altering these settings to achieve my desired results I'm all ears :)

> .wav file1 info
>   Effect 
>   Start playing --> From beginning
>   Stop Playing --> After 31 slides
>
> Timing 
>   Start --> After Previous
>   Triggers --> Animate as part of click sequence
>
> .wav file2 info
>   Effect
>   Start playing --> from last position
>   Stop playing --> after 34 slides
>
> Timing
>   Start playing --> after previous
>   Triggers --> Animate as part of click sequence
>
> .wav file3 info
>   Effect
>   Start playing --> from last position
>   Stop playing --> after 19 slides
>
> Timing
>   Start playing --> after previous
>   Triggers --> Animate as part of click sequence
>
> .wav file4 info
>   Effect
>   Start playing --> from last position
>   Stop playing --> after 19 slides
>
> Timing
>   Start playing --> after previous
>   Triggers --> Animate as part of click sequence